# Wordpress: if this post in single view has specific tag not show post thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

How can i do this in WordPress loop:
If this post in single view has **specific tag (like: video)** not show post thumbnail!

I tried this in loop, but this code not working correctly:

```
<?php if ( is_tag( 'video' ) ) { ?>
       // do nothing
       <?php }else{ ?>
    <div class="single-img">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`has_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/) function:

```
<?php if ( has_tag( 'video' ) ) { ?>
       // do nothing
<?php }else{ ?>
    <div class="single-img">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```